# multiple from in a page, need to pass data

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple form. I recognized it with formId. when I click on submit button it shows only first form ID... say 22 for all.

sample of form code:

```
<form name="hid_form<?php echo$form_id;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="formid" value="<?php echo $form_id;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="batch2" value="<?php echo $std['batch'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="res_reg" value="Result(Regular)"/>
</form>
```

and script code:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSubmitForm()
{
var TestVar = document.getElementById("formid").value;
    alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);
// will go to another page
}
</script>`
```

If I can recognized the form on click. almost prob will solve. 
please any Idea????

Comment: Make the form_id dynamic <input type="hidden" name="id" id="<?php echo $form_id;?>" value="<?php echo $form_id;?>" /> . OnSubmitForm(formid) pass the dynamic id. Change this line var TestVar = document.getElementById(formid).value;

Comment: Take note that if you are using [HTML id Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_id.asp), the value must be unique within the HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the form Id in your submit function and read it on that function

```
<form name="hid_form<?php echo$form_id;?>" id="hid_form<?php echo$form_id;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm(<?php echo$form_id;?>);" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="formid<?php echo$form_id;?>" value="<?php echo $form_id;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="batch2" id="batch2<?php echo$form_id;?>" value="<?php echo $std['batch'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="res_reg" value="Result(Regular)"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSubmitForm(formId)
{

    alert ("You clicked on form no : " + formId);
    var batch2 = $("#batch2"+formId).val() ;
    $("#hid_form"+formId).submit();
}
</script>
```

Note: Make sure when you are using multiple forms on a single page, the form field Ids should be unique.

Comment: thanks it works......... great you, Saroj. Can u suggest or sample code so that I can acees the name "batch2" value. individually now.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a hiddent input with form id.